# NGINX - rewrite and proxy all host/app/* to cdn

Tags: angular, nginx, cdn

I have a 'front' page on www.host.com and a SPA on www.host.com/app.

The front-end files for the SPA are hosted on a CDN, url = www.cdn.host.com/app.

For some reason I cannot get nginx to properly re-route all www.host.com/app* to www.cdn.host.com/app to load the files from CDN, because it starts to either get in a redirect loop www.host.com/app/app/app/app/app, or it does nothing etc

```
location ~ ^/app {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ / break;
  proxy_pass http://cdn/app/app;
  proxy_redirect     off;
  proxy_set_header   Host $host;
}
```

it works with this config:

```
location /app {
  proxy_pass http://cdn/app;
  proxy_set_header   Host $host;
  proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
}
```

but the Angular app uses HTML5 routes, and thus the url gets updated to www.host.com/app/auth/login. All good until I refresh the page then nginx tries to load app/auth/login from the CDN and gives a 404..

So nginx should rewrite all url's that start with /app/* to just /app and then into the proxy pass, is that correct?

many thanks

Comment: You have strange `rewrite` rule that also overrides the URI appended to the `proxy_pass` directive. Start by removing the `rewrite` statement and using `proxy_pass http://cdn;` with no URI or trailing `/`.

Comment: Thanks @RichardSmith, i have been trying all kind of stuff so bit weird now indeed. It works when I remove the rewrite and set proxy_pass http://cdn/app (its in a subfolder app on the CDN).

But if I reload the page (url = https://test.sphingx.com/app/auth/login), it gets a 404, cause it tries to find auth/login on the CDN, and should rewrite the URL for the CDN to http://cdn/app .. To load the front-end files again.. Any tips? Thanks!